# error handling asp.net mvc 5 doesn't let stack trace to be viewed on event viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have handled error 500 and 404 in web.config

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace"> --><!--defaultPath="/Errors/NotFound"--><!--
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Errors/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Errors/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

But the problem is that currently I can't see 500 and 404 errors in event viewer and their corresponding stack trace

I have  used Microsoft application insights up an error handling on Application_Error but it's not as descriptive as event viewer

```
     protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();

        var httpStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        try
        {
            httpStatusCode = ((HttpException) exception).GetHttpCode();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        var ip = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

        var userName = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        catch
        {
        }

       var url = string.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
             url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
        }


        var log = string.Format("Url: {0} , httpStatusCode: {1}, " +
                                "dateTime: {2}, exceptionMessage: {3}, " +
                                "ipAddress: {4}, userName: {5} ",
            url, httpStatusCode, dateTime, exception.Message, ip, userName);

        ServerAnalytics.CurrentRequest.LogEvent(log);

    }
```

I need to have clear error logging like event viewer

what should I do?

what are the other options? newrelic, application insights?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the exception stack trace in your logging. Instead of using exception.message in your error logging, use exception.ToString(), which will include the stack trace.

Comment: Are you using Server.ClearError anywhere in your code?